# How can I change an array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I want to convert numbers (inputted by user) into an array.
These are the inputs:

```
<input id="x1_y1" class="v x1 y1">
<input id="x2_y1" class="v x2 y1">
<input id="x3_y1" class="v x3 y1">
<input id="x4_y1" class="v x4 y1">
<input id="x5_y1" class="v x5 y1">
<input id="x6_y1" class="v x6 y1">
<input id="x7_y1" class="v x7 y1">
<input id="x8_y1" class="v x8 y1">
<input id="x9_y1" class="v x9 y1">

<input id="x1_y2" class="v x1 y2">
<input id="x2_y2" class="v x2 y2">
<input id="x3_y2" class="v x3 y2">
<input id="x4_y2" class="v x4 y2">
<input id="x5_y2" class="v x5 y2">
<input id="x6_y2" class="v x6 y2">
<input id="x7_y2" class="v x7 y2">
<input id="x8_y2" class="v x8 y2">
<input id="x9_y2" class="v x9 y2">

<input id="x1_y3" class="v x1 y3">
<input id="x2_y3" class="v x2 y3">
<input id="x3_y3" class="v x3 y3">
<!-- etc.... -->
```

Of who I have stored the ids in javascript.

```
h1 = ["x1_y1","x2_y1","x3_y1","x1_y2","x2_y2","x3_y2","x1_y3","x2_y3","x3_y3"];
h2 = ["x4_y1","x5_y1","x6_y1","x4_y2","x5_y2","x6_y2","x4_y3","x5_y3","x6_y3"];
h3 = ["x7_y1","x8_y1","x9_y1","x7_y2","x8_y2","x9_y2","x7_y3","x8_y3","x9_y3"];
h4 = ["x1_y4","x2_y4","x3_y4","x1_y5","x2_y5","x3_y5","x1_y6","x2_y6","x3_y6"];
h5 = ["x4_y4","x5_y4","x6_y4","x4_y5","x5_y5","x6_y5","x4_y6","x5_y6","x6_y6"];
// etc....
```

I also got these empty arrays to store the inputted numbers:

```
valueH1=["","","","","","","","",""];
valueH2=["","","","","","","","",""];
valueH3=["","","","","","","","",""];
valueH4=["","","","","","","","",""];
valueH5=["","","","","","","","",""];
// etc....
```

Then I use the ids in the first arrays to get the numbers I want to place in the second.

```
for(i=0;i<9;i++){
    var oldStr = "h1["+i+"]";
    eval("valueH1["+i+"]") = document.getElementById(eval(oldStr)).value;
};
alert(valueH1.join('\n'));
```

But this doesn't work. What is going wrong or is there a way easier solution?

Comment: You really want to generate these procedurally. This is completely out of control in terms of rampant and unnecessary duplication. Try and avoid using `eval` unless it's an absolute last resort. In this case your use is not only pointless, it's invalid.

Comment: You're definitely in the wrong way...

Comment: u don't need `eval`...

Comment: Do you have jQuery loaded?

Comment: You can generate all of those `<input>` fields programmatically using arbitrary X and Y ranges, plus use similar code to extract values and save those into a regular data structure, perhaps an array of arrays. Using heaps of independent variables with no relationship other than name is a huge problem.

Comment: You do not need to use `eval` for `h1[0]` because that code works as-is without the eval. I have no idea where you got the idea that you need `eval` to *access an element in an array* but it suggests you need a much better JavaScript reference to work from. A good place to start is the [Mozilla JavaScript documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/bm/docs/Web/JavaScript) but there are many good books which are also invaluable for someone looking to learn the correct way of doing things.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've just started coding so I'm figuring things out as I go. I think I need to study a bit more before I start this. Thanks for the reference.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `eval` and you might need to do a bit of studying on how to optimize your programming logic...but just to get your current code working, you would do something like.

```
for(i=0;i<9;i++){
  var oldStr = h1[i];
  valueH1[i] = document.getElementById(oldStr).value;
};
alert(valueH1.join('\n'));
```